# Navbar with sidebar in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar of bootstrap and a sidebar and I want to make this

[image]

but i obtain this

[image]

I can't make the navbar appear in front of the sidebar.

Comment: Please make a snippet or a fiddle and post your code in your question as well for future users who may encounter the same issue.

Comment: I don't see any CSS in your current shared example. The only thing in there is `-`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ks5cee3m/1/ my fiddle is here!

Answer (score 0):

Play with `z-index` properly and it works good :

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/ks5cee3m/2/)

```
.navbar{
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative; 
    z-index:2;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #8CCA59;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute` for the navbar (you may want this in a media query so it only applies to larger screens). Then add `position:relative` to your `#wrapper`.

You can then use `z-index` to put the navbar "above" the wrapper...:

Relevant CSS (I added an ID to your navbar):

```
#navbar
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:100;
}

#wrapper {
  position:relative;
  z-index:50;
  ...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebvqcq26/